# Error after installing R 4.3.3, showing "Fatal error:'R_TempDir' contains space

Tags: r

I tried to download the latest version (R-4.3.3) of R on my windows computer and received this error message upon trying to open the program. "Fatal error: 'R_TempDir' contains space". Has anyone ever had this issue or have any ideas on how to resolve it? I have tried reinstalling the program and moving where the program is stored but no luck.

I tried two solutions :

- drop all Rdata files and reinstall R and then R studio
- install R and Rstudio without connection

Comment: Please provide your Windows version and where you obtained your R - installer from, and the Rstudio version.    Next: will `R`  run from a terminal session or with `r.gui` app?